Why Altering MySQL Table by Adding NOT NULL Constraint Caused MySQL Server Unresponsiveness
We attempted a migration on MySQL v8.0.21 with the following command:
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY guid binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(uuid()));
This command was applied to several tables, some of which are large and in constant use. Despite scheduling the migration during off-peak hours, the MySQL server became unresponsive for about a minute (last minute) when altering one of the most frequently used tables containing approximately 2 million records. The alter command took around 13 minutes to complete. Interestingly, the table was not locked during the operation, yet it caused MySQL become unresponsive.
Query_time: 799.728263  Lock_time: 0.000129 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
Query_time: 839.289505  Lock_time: 0.000275 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
The guid field already had the default constraint DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(uuid())) from a previous migration. We observed an increase in threads, RAM, and CPU usage, but it was not near the limit. Another question is why it took so long to execute and only caused disruption on the last minute? Did it execute for whole 800 seconds or not?
According to the MySQL documentation, such an operation should not cause disruptions as it is supposed to lock only the table's metadata briefly, allowing CRUD operations to continue. However, there is no clear documentation on whether an existing default constraint will be re-applied if specified again in the ALTER command. Some sources suggest that omitting the default constraint when altering the NOT NULL constraint might leave the default constraint intact, but our experience showed otherwise, leading us to include the default constraint in our ALTER commands.
Documentation and Proof

MySQL Documentation on ALTER TABLE and Metadata Locks: According to the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual, ALTER TABLE operations typically require metadata locks which should only block other operations that need an exclusive lock on the same table for a short period. For most operations, including adding a NOT NULL constraint, this lock should not prevent SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations.
Handling of Default Constraints: The MySQL ALTER TABLE documentation mentions that adding or changing a default value for a column does not inherently cause disruption unless it requires a table rebuild, which should be minimal for adding constraints unless the table is very large.
Performance Implications: Community discussions and best practices suggest that altering large tables, especially with NOT NULL constraints, can be resource-intensive and might lead to temporary unresponsiveness.

References

MySQL Documentation on Metadata Locking
MySQL ALTER TABLE Documentation
MySQL Handling of Default Values
Community Discussions on ALTER TABLE Performance
Best Practices for Large ALTER TABLE Operations


Is guid column part of an index? If so, you may consider to remove the index, alter the table, and then recreate the index.

Please provide the SHOW CREATE TABLE before and after the migration.  This should clarify some subtle issues that are not included in the Question.  Also, the version before and after the migration.

Also, were there any NULLs in the affected column before the migration?

Thank you both.
@Daniels118 yes, guid is part of the index. Wouldn't removing and adding index take more time on a big table?
@RickJames We ensured that there were no NULL values on the column before the migration, since we did populate all before running. I'll look into SHOW CREATE TABLE and see if there is some more insights to help answering this one.

If you delete the index and run the ALTER, then you will discover if the latency is caused by the index or not. At least we can restrict the research.
